# Отфильтровать массивы

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
const colorsList = [
  {
    name: 'red',
    hex: '#ff0000',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    hex: '#ffffff',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    order: 0,
   },
   {
    name: 'blue',
    hex: '#0000ff',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
    order: 3,
   },
   {
    name: 'green',
    hex: '#00ff00',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    order: 2,
   },
   {
    name: 'black',
    hex: '#000000',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    order: -1,
   },
  ];
```

Мне нужно чтоб после фильтрации остались они:

```
   {
    name: 'red',
    hex: '#ff0000',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    order: 1,
  },


  {
    name: 'blue',
    hex: '#0000ff',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
    order: 3,
   },

 
    {
    name: 'green',
    hex: '#00ff00',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    order: 2,
   },
```

Как можно организовать в js

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: принцип фильтрации то не хотите описать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно применить метод filer массива. Получается примерно так:

```js
const colorsList = [
  {
    name: 'red',
    hex: '#ff0000',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    hex: '#ffffff',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    order: 0,
   },
   {
    name: 'blue',
    hex: '#0000ff',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
    order: 3,
   },
   {
    name: 'green',
    hex: '#00ff00',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    order: 2,
   },
   {
    name: 'black',
    hex: '#000000',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    order: -1,
   },
  ];
  
  const filteredList = colorsList.filter(({name})=> name == 'red'|| name == 'blue'|| name == 'green' )
  
  console.log(filteredList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял нужно сохранить в массиве те объекты, которые имеют значение свойства order больше нуля, собственно сам код внизу.

```js
const colorsList = [{
    name: 'red',
    hex: '#ff0000',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    order: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'white',
    hex: '#ffffff',
    rgb: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    order: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'blue',
    hex: '#0000ff',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
    order: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'green',
    hex: '#00ff00',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    order: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'black',
    hex: '#000000',
    rgb: 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
    order: -1,
  },
];


let filteredColorsList = colorsList.filter((item) => item.order > 0);

console.log(filteredColorsList);
```